# Call sed in linux

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I need to replace some string into another in files. I know how to do that with single file: `sed -i 's/a/b/'`. But what about recursive function? I think I have to use `find . -name *` with xargs somehow.

I need your help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct, `find` and `xargs` are what you want to use. Here's an example which will find all files with the ".ext" file extension in the current folder and all subfolders ,and replace the letter `a` with the letter `b` in the files.

```
find . -name "*.ext" | xargs sed -i 's/a/b/g'
```

Comment: `sed: couldn't edit .: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit ./.git/objects/68: not a regular file`

Comment: I'm trying to chage some in my git repo. And I get that error.

Comment: What are you using instead of "*.ext" in the find? If it's "*" that will also match directories, which sed won't work on. Add "-type f" into the find command to only get regular files.